# Stored Procedure Unsuccessful Insertion message Show

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I wrote the following code. I need to check for an unsuccessful insert. i.e `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1` because I want to show a message for that error situation. Will you have any suggestions?

```
if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
{
    lblInserted.Text = "Inserted:" + count;
    // MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
    lblInserted.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(lblInserted.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    lblInserted.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    count++;
    dataGridViewDisplayPanel.Rows[i].Cells[nextCell - 1].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
    dataGridViewDisplayPanel.Rows[i].Cells[nextCell - 1].Value = "Inserted Successfully";
}
```

Comment: Also if no rows inserted ExecuteNonQuery() will return 0. But it's not a good idea to use !=1 because could be inserted more than one row. So use !=0. Or you can use try catch like in the answer below if you need to catch an exception.

Comment: OK sir I will try IT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually ExecuteNonQuery throws an exception if it is unsuccessful - have a look at this:

```
try
{
    // run the query
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    lblInserted.Text = "Inserted:" + count;
    // MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
    lblInserted.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(lblInserted.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    lblInserted.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    count++;
    dataGridViewDisplayPanel.Rows[i].Cells[nextCell - 1].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
    dataGridViewDisplayPanel.Rows[i].Cells[nextCell - 1].Value = "Inserted Successfully";
}
catch (Exception ee9)
{
    // Deal with the error
    MessageBox.Show("Oops, it failed");
}
```